# htaccess broken filename with space

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, whitespace, filenames

I can't figure out how to make filenames with spaces in them correctly named when downloaded. The name gets broken at the first space. eg. the file

```
how are you.pdf
```

is downloaded as

```
how
```

Below is my code. I have tried many things and none have worked this far.

```
RewriteEngine On
##RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?consciousnesscoachingacademy.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(.*)$ - [NC,F,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^filename=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^download\.php$ %1
RewriteRule (.*) - [E=file:$1]
Header set Content-type "octet-stream"
Header set Content-disposition "attachment; filename=%{file}e" env=file
```

Comment: Interesting question. I'm not even sure there's a real spec on how file names should be encoded in `Content-disposition` and similar HTTP headers so I wonder if mod_headers has the right tools.

Comment: The filename should be wrapped in double quotes, as [per the spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1). `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="how are you.pdf"`. This will fix your issue with files being downloaded as `how`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?consciousnesscoachingacademy.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(.*)$ - [NC,F,L]

# file download (attachment)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /download\.php\?filename=(.+)\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^download\.php$ %1? [E=file:%1]

Header set "Content-disposition" "attachment; filename=\"%{REDIRECT_file}e\""
Header set "Content-type" "octet-stream"
```

Comment: It does make the file downloadable with the correct extension now, but: it replaces the spaces with %20. Any way to fix that too?

Comment: No this rule doesn't convert space to `%20`, it gets converted in your browser itself.

Comment: Even replacing them with underscores would be perfect

Comment: for some reason, it now just goes back to the homepage instead of downloading the file

Comment: I've rolled back that change otherwise code is getting too complex and downloaded filename should not be tampered anyway.

Comment: thank you a lot for your help, we'll survive those %20s